# what is the change in macro expansion when using environ and newenviron as compared to the standard environment

Tags: environments, expansion

The packages `environ` and `newenviron` both provide an alternative to the standard environment macros included with LaTeX. The main difference is that they make it possible to refer to the environment body using a macro, but another difference is that macro expansion is affected as can be seen by (un)commenting the relevant lines in the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{newenviron}

\def\speakify#1: #2\par{{\bfseries#1}: {\itshape``#2\unskip''}\par}
\newenvironment{interview}{\everypar{\speakify}}{\par}
%\NewEnviron{interview}{\everypar{\speakify}\BODY\par}
%\newenviron{interview}{}{\everypar{\speakify}\envbody\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{interview}
I: I have a question for you that I would really like to know the answer to. Could you please explain it in your own words while the moon is still high in the sky? That would be lovely thank you very much!

L: Of course I will answer gladly all questions you might have no matter how silly I feel they may be provided payment is made in full before commencement of the answering phase.
\end{interview}
\end{document}
```

What exactly is the change in macro expansion that occurs?

Comment: The main point of `environ` is that you can access the content of an environment with the command \BODY.  Standard environments do not have such a facility.

Comment: A feature of `NewDocumentEnvironment` from `xparse` package is, that the arguments can be accessed in the `end code` section as well, which is not possible for the standard `\newenvironment`

Comment: I haven't heard of `newenviron` previously but I am a big fan of `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and `\NewEnviron` from [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ). The former gives much more control over the arguments to the environment and the latter makes it possible to work with the body of the environment.

Comment: There is no change in macro expansion; the `environ` or `newenviron` codes just grab the environment's contents. You don't need them in this application.

Comment: @egreg: as is the document gives an error message because the final \par of the environment seems to be put in too late or something, but with the other environments it works.

Comment: @hkBst I wouldn't go with your approach to begin with. I see no need for quotes, for instance: the label already delimit the speech lines.

Comment: egreg the example is just to illustrate that something is going on with regard to macro expansion. Without understanding what is going on better it is hard to come up with a better example.

Comment: @hkBst there is nothing going on with macro expansion. The last `\speakify` just doesn't get see the `\par` in `\endinterview`. Add a blank line before `\end{interview}` and the error is gone.

Comment: @clemens I understand that, but the alternative environments do not seem to need that...

Comment: @hkBst yes because in the others there is a **non-hidden** `\par` directly after `\BODY` so `\speakify` gets to see it before the environment ends.

Comment: @clemens but it has to wind up at the end of the real body somehow. The standard environment solution also has a \par that is supposed to go in at the end, but it arrives too alte so to speak. What makes the \par for the alternative environments arrive on time?

Comment: @hkBst the standard env has `\par` but inside the definition of `\endinterview` (which is called by `\end{interview}`). But `\speakify` needs to see a literal `\par` token. The last `\speakify` never gets to see it, though. What it sees, is the tokens `\end`, `{`, `i`, `n`, `t`, `e`, `r`, `v`, `i`, `e`, `w`, and `}`.

Answer (score 2):

After the `\everypar` processing of the second paragraph, with the document as posted you have essentially

```
\speakify L: Of course I will answer gladly all questions you might have no matter how
             silly I feel they may be provided payment is made in full before commencement
             of the answering phase.\end{interview} \end{document}
```

Now `\speakify` sees `L` as `#1` but runs off the end of the document looking for `\par` to delimit `#2`. So you get:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \speakify.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*>
```

If you edit the document so there is a paragraph break after the  environment so the file ends

```
phase.
\end{interview}

\end{document}
```

Then `\speakify` would include `\end{interview}` in `#2` so the above error is avoided but the grouping logic is messed up and you get:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.16 

?
```

If you edit the document to put a paragraph break *before* the end of the envitonment, so the file ends:

```
 phase.

\end{interview}
\end{document}
```

Then the document works without error.

---

The expansion  logic is different in the forms using `\BODY` as you have added an explicit `\par` so `\BODY` is expanded and when the final paragraph is processed, `\par` is already in the input stream so the processing is equivalent to

```
\speakify L: Of course I will answer gladly all questions you might have no matter how
             silly I feel they may be provided payment is made in full before commencement
             of the answering phase.\par
```

and `\speakify` sees its argument delimiter as intended.

Comment: So are you saying that the standard environment only adds the closing argument (\par in my case) when \end{interview} is expanded, while the non-standard environments first determine the entire extent of the environment and so (can) put in the closing par straight away?

Comment: @hkBst yes, in your neweviron forms you have `\BODY\par` so in fact the closing `\par`  is first into the input stream and the actual paragraph is added at the next step, after `\BODY` is expanded.